# How can I prove this trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

$sin(11x)+sin(9x) = (sin(10x)cos(x)+cos(10x)sin(x))+(sin(10x)cos(x)−cos(10x)sin(x))  = 2sin(10x)cos(x)
$

I dont understand how you go from the left hand side $sin(11x) + sin(9x)$ to the right hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Using $$\displaystyle \bullet \; \sin(A+B) = \sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B$$

And $$\displaystyle \bullet \; \sin(A-B) = \sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B$$

So $$\sin(11x) = \sin (10x+x) =\sin10x \cos x+\cos 10 x\sin x.......(1)$$

and $$\sin (9x) = \sin (10x-x) =\sin10x \cos x-\cos 10 x\sin x.........(2)$$

Now Add these two equation, We get

$$\sin (11x)+\sin (9x) = 2\sin 10x\cos x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin { 11x } =\sin { \left( 10x+x \right) =\sin { 10x\cos { x } +\cos { 10x\sin { x }  }  }  } \\ $$
$$\sin { 9x } =\sin { \left( 10x-x \right) =\sin { 10x\cos { x } -\cos { 10x\sin { x }  }  }  } \\ $$